# Not able to cache HttpResponse using cachingHttpClient in android

Tags: java, android

```
public class CacheDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CacheConfig cacheConfig = new CacheConfig();
    cacheConfig.setMaxCacheEntries(1000);
    cacheConfig.setMaxObjectSizeBytes(1024 * 1024);

    HttpClient cachingClient = new CachingHttpClient(new DefaultHttpClient(), cacheConfig);

    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

    sendRequest(cachingClient, localContext);
    CacheResponseStatus responseStatus = (CacheResponseStatus) localContext.getAttribute(
            CachingHttpClient.CACHE_RESPONSE_STATUS);
    checkResponse(responseStatus);


    sendRequest(cachingClient, localContext);
    responseStatus = (CacheResponseStatus) localContext.getAttribute(
            CachingHttpClient.CACHE_RESPONSE_STATUS);
    checkResponse(responseStatus);
}

static void sendRequest(HttpClient cachingClient, HttpContext localContext) {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.mydomain.com/content/");
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = cachingClient.execute(httpget, localContext);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    try {
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static void checkResponse(CacheResponseStatus responseStatus) {
    switch (responseStatus) {
        case CACHE_HIT:
            System.out.println("A response was generated from the cache with no requests "
                    + "sent upstream");
            break;
        case CACHE_MODULE_RESPONSE:
            System.out.println("The response was generated directly by the caching module");
            break;
        case CACHE_MISS:
            System.out.println("The response came from an upstream server");
            break;
        case VALIDATED:
            System.out.println("The response was generated from the cache after validating "
                    + "the entry with the origin server");
            break;
    }
}

}
```

It is not worked for me.

Every time it get the data from the server.not from the cache.

I m using jar `"httpclient-cache-4.1-beta1"`.

Comment: Could you please share the link for CachingHttpClient? It seems it's not in the Android SDK.

Comment: Never mind, got it from [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi). I'm having the same issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't showed us what's going on with your HTTP server. Is the service at mydomain.com/content setting the correct Cache-Control headers on the HTTP response? For caching to work, you need to have your HTTP server or web application indicate if the data can be cached and the length that the data can be cached using the appropriate headers.

Also, check the API documented on CachingHttpClient to see what headers it expects from the web server.

Comment: what parameter is needed to be set in my web application(which is written in php) and what should be written in request and response in the server-end.and how to handled the cache in my android

Comment: i have added code to removeheader from my android code. even the it returns cache_miss.